# passing int as parameter from JSP to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass studentId of datatype **int** to servlet but it does not accept it and forces to change the datatype to String

```
    int studentId;
    String studentName;

    studentId = request.getParameter("StudentId");   // (cannot convert from int to String).
```

I can't change it to String as in the database studentId is an integer (primary key) and my java class also takes an int as a parameter.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to parse the parameter as an int.  In a request the parameters are just strings at the end of the day (they were typed into a browser, or stored in the html of a webpage after all), so you need to interpret it on the server as the type you expect.

```
studentId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("StudentId"));
```

Comment: Please check with if condition as !=null, if you use integer.parseint();

Answer (score 2):

```
private int roll;

int roll = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("roll"));
```

Here `request` is the object of `HttpServletRequest` and hence it will the `getParameter()` and we are getting the value as `string`.

Answer (score 0):

What about Mobileno?

```
int amobile;
amobile = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amobile"));
//raising an exception
```